# Interacting with multiple stored values within a field in Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, apache-zeppelin

I am currently working with a field in pig that contains multiple values.  I am looking to count users by product by location and I used `LOAD` to create data in the following format: `(Location, {(product1), (product2), (product3)}, numOfUsers)`.  I am looking to separate out each of the products and treat them as separate entities meaning i'd like to end up with the following:

```
(location, (product1), numOfUsers)
(location, (product2), numOfUsers)
(location, (product3), numOfUsers)
```

I believe I need to use some sort of nested `FOREACH` function, but i'm a bit lost.  Num of users for each product contained in the same tuple will be the same since they are grouped and that's perfectly fine.  I am a beginner (started with Pig 3 days ago) so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.  I believe I would use `FLATTEN`?

Answer (score 0):

```
FOREACH A GENERATE location, FLATTEN(products) AS product, numOfUsers;
```

Solved the issue.  This created a cross product of all records that were stored within the bag.  Used http://www.st.ewi.tudelft.nl/~hauff/BDP-Lectures/9_10_advanced_pig.pdf for reference.  Very useful resource.